# Optimise project with r.js and include already r.js optimised modules

Tags: optimization, requirejs, r.js

I have two apps that use RequireJS. One uses the other as a plugin, a module of sorts if you will. The plugin/module is optimised already using `r.js`.

When I run the app on my server everything works fine, in this state the app isn't optimised yet, only the plugin/module.

When I go to optimise the app via `r.js` and I include the plugin/module `r.js` throws an error because it can't find files that the plugin/module uses but ultimately gets bundled in when the plugin/module gets optimised.

So how do I get round this? I think I have the following options:

1. As I build my main app I include the unoptimised plugin/module and optimise it all at once.
2. I add all the URLs in the optimised plugin/module to the config and point them to `:empty`, but that's going to be a ball ache as those paths are *dynamic*.

So what else can I do? Is there a way to tell `r.js` to either:

1. Don't bother looking for the required paths in my optimised plugin/module.
2. Somehow compile my plugin/mobile but remove all traces of `define` and `require` from it, thus making it self contained, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got around the issue by including my plugin/module as a dependancy rather than part of the application.

Since it's a good idea to have a main config file for your app, I told `r.js` to use this but then spoofed the URL for my plugin/module to the special `empty:` value.

This then stopped `r.js` trying to find all the dependancies of the already optimised plugin/module and allowed me to include it as a dependancy; all is now well.